# Meteor "update failed: Access denied" when user attempts to update their own profile?

Tags: meteor

Im adding a field to a user's account on creation. This is working fine:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.groups = [2];
  return user;
});
```

I need to make a function that allows the user to change this. When I run this from the front-end I get an error "update failed: Access denied"

```
Meteor.users.update(
  { _id: Meteor.userId() },
  {
    $set: { groups: [4, 5] },
  },
);
```

In server/main.js I have:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: { groups: 1 } });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a db update directly from the client (front end)?

Comment: Yes. I take it thats not allowed?

Comment: Open up your dev console and run ```Meteor.users.findOne()``` See if you get ```groups``` in the user object. Either way, you must be very careful while updating the db from a client. Clients are not to be trusted as a rule of thumb

Comment: Ah, groups isn't there. I thought it would be available as I published it (see my question update).

Comment: You aslo need this in order to allow users to modify other fields. But it's a security hazard I feel:  ```Meteor.users.allow()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make db updates from the client directly. No client can ever be trusted.

Having said that, there are two ways to deal with this:

#### ONE

[As per the documentation :](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users)

> By default, the current user’s username, emails and profile are
>   published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the
>   current user with:

```
// Server
Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, {
      fields: { groups: 1 }
    });
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function(userId, user) {
    return true;

```
/**
 * Don't use `return true` in production!
 * You probably need something like this:
 * return Meteor.users.findOne(userId).profile.isAdmin;
 */
```

}
});

```
// Client
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
```

[Meteor allow rules](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-allow)

### TWO

Define a meteor method in the server and have the server update the relevant data for you AFTER it does some validations. Server code is always trusted.

**server.js**

```
Meteor.method({
updateGroups: function(data){
 // make changes to the user record
});
```